# how to prevent C++ output/console form closing in this case

Tags: c++, runtime, cin

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<cstdio>
#include"dos.h"

int sum(int &a, int &b)
{
    a++;
    b++;
    return (a)+(b);
}

int  main()
{ 
    int a, b;
    cout << "Enter a and b";
    cout << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    int sum1;
    sum1= sum(a, b);
    cout << endl << sum1;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

If I comment any one of the `cin.get()` lines, the program closes (i.e the output screen) after completion.

Is it because I have to press enter twice (for entering values) and the last 'enter key' closes the program after its done completing the program?

Comment: It doesn't close the program. The program ends and it closes itself. What keeps it from closing is waiting for an input from `std::cin::get`, but as you correctly ovserved, if you press `enter`, your first `cin.get()` will consume it, since `std::cin >>` does not remove the last `enter` from input buffer

Comment: I like using `std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n')` to pause the console.  There are other methods, search the internet for "C++ pause console".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since I was using visual studio but I'm using this code and I have no problem.

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
```

Comment: Your answer does not explain anything. Please avoid "this works for me" and/or pure code answers. Provide some explanation to your solutions

Comment: what does cin.ingnore() does?